# How to make a scatter plot of multiple data?

Tags: r, plot

I have to make a scatter plot of the 50 US states. I have to plot their of population, income, illiteracy, life expectancy, murder rate, high school graduation rate, average number of freezing days, and total land area with a scatter plot.

I thought doing `plot(state)` would be enough but I get an error "object `state` not found". Doing `plot(state.x77)` gives me a plot of income by population but that's it. It doesn't show plots of the other variables.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: perhaps `pairs(state)`

Comment: @mtoto I get :object `state` not found"

Comment: @mtoto When I do `pairs(state.x77)` it gives me what looks to be the scatter plot.

Comment: @mtoto I guess doing `pairs(state.x77)` worked. BTW do you know how I would do a significance test on the variables inside `state.x77` such as `Population`, `Income`, and `Murder`? I tried doing something like `cor.test(state.x77.Population, state.x77.Income, method="method")` but I got an error "`state.x77.Population` not found"

Comment: You are calling the variables wrong. Using `cor.test(state.x77[,'Population'], state.x77[,'Income'])` should give you what you want.

Comment: @Jaap Thanks a lot